# How to mock method returning object using CppUTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cpputest

I've following method:

```
QMap<QString, int> DefaultConfig::getConfig()
{
    QMap<QString, int> result;
    result.insert("Error", LOG_LOCAL0);
    result.insert("Application", LOG_LOCAL1);
    result.insert("System", LOG_LOCAL2);
    result.insert("Debug", LOG_LOCAL3);
    result.insert("Trace", LOG_LOCAL4);
    return result;
}
```

an I try to write mock which can return QMap prepared in test:

```
QMap<QString, int> DefaultConfig::getConfig() {
    mock().actualCall("getConfig");
    return ?
}
```

but I don't know how to mock the return value? I would like to use the mock in following way in `TEST` function:

```
QMap<QString, int> fake_map;
fake_map.insert("ABC", 1);
mock().expectOneCall("getConfig").andReturnValue(fake_map);
```

I cannot find such example in CppUTest Mocking documentation. I also know that `.andReturnValue` in this form will also not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the object by-value / -reference, ***pass by-pointer***.

---

### Example:

<sub>(I'm using an `std::map` here – `QMap` is exactly the same)</sub>

#### Mock

You get the return value for the mock by the `return#####Value()` methods. Since `returnPointerValue()` returns a `void*` you have to cast it to proper pointer type. Then you can return by-value by dereferencing that pointer.

```
std::map<std::string, int> getConfig()
{
    auto returnValue = mock().actualCall("getConfig")
                                .returnPointerValue();
    return *static_cast<std::map<std::string, int>*>(returnValue);
}
```

#### Test

The expected return value is passed by pointer:

```
TEST(MapMockTest, mockReturningAMap)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> expected = { {"abc", 123} };
    mock().expectOneCall("getConfig").andReturnValue(&expected);

    auto cfg = getConfig();
    CHECK_EQUAL(123, cfg["abc"]);
}
```

Please not, there's a difference between *Pointer* and *ConstPointer*.